# Protobuf - Refuses to link vs2013 or vs2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, protocol-buffers

As the title states I cannot get [protobuf](https://github.com/google/protobuf) to link successfully.

Here is the small test program. note the `AddressBook` class was generated usin gthe protoc compiler that was built when i compiled protobuf.Additionally, this proto file is part of googles protobuf examples that is included with the source.

```
#define PROTOBUF_USE_DLLS
#include <iostream>
#include "addressbook.pb.h"

#pragma comment(lib, "libprotocd.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "libprotobufd.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "libprotobuf-lited.lib")

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
  tutorial::AddressBook ab;
  return 0;
}
```

Here are the errors I am receiving.

```
LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const * const google::protobuf::internal::empty_string_" (?empty_string_@internal@protobuf@google@@3PEBV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@EB)

LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__int64 google::protobuf::internal::empty_string_once_init_" (?empty_string_once_init_@internal@protobuf@google@@3_JA)
```

**Some assertions:**

1. Same code running on linux.. *With the exception of -lprotoc -lprotobuf -lprotobuf-lite vs. the #pregma stuff*
2. Happens both in VS2013 and VS2015
3. Tried both 3.0-Release and latest code from git. Same issue.
4. I have tried this with both the `debug`target as well as the `release` (when using release removed trailing `d` from library name) target
5. Made sure that both the additional `include` and `library` directories were set in the VS project. `linker --> General --> Additional Library Directories` is set to the place where the compiled .dll are located`

At this point I pretty much turned my attention to google to see what I could find. I ran across the following.

1. [2015 not fully supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31681798/compile-protocol-buffers-2-6-1-using-vs-2015). It was old, but figured I would try vs2013
2. [protobuf dynamic linking](https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/cmake/README.md) Yes. When building with cmake I enabled shared library support and have the #define in my program
3. [disable inline expansion](https://github.com/google/protobuf/issues/812)

Still, not able to progress past the above errors. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you check project properties > Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies?

Comment: the linker cannot find the libraries. have you set the library search path. IN 2013 its in the vs setup (not project specific), in 2015 its in the project (or in the vs setup)

Comment: `__int64 google::protobuf::internal::empty_string_once_init_` and `google::protobuf::internal::empty_string_`?

The linker is stating those two functions do not exist in the libraries provided.  Have you tried searching for them to see if they exist in the source code, and if so, where they ever compiled into the library?

Comment: @AndyG I checked and it was empty. I thought the `#pragma` took care of the linking, but I could be wrong. To play it on the safe side I added the additional libs, but still receiving the same error.

Comment: @AndyG I think that the `#pragma comment` effectively makes `Additional Dependencies` not necessary.  What does matter is the search path.

Comment: @pm100 hmm.. I'm not 100% I follow you. I don't use VS much so please understand this might be ignorance, but isn't `linker --> General --> Additional Library Directories` what you're talking about?

Comment: @Freddy -- You still need to set the path in the `Additional Library Directories`, even if you have the `#pragma comment` lines.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yup. I have that. I'll update the post to reflect this as well.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I'm checking now.

Comment: needs to point at the .lib files not at the .dll files

Comment: @pm100 both are in the same place. When you build cmake/vs dump the `.dll` and `.lib` to the same directory. The dll are copied to the binary folder where main is built.

Comment: anyway - the linker cant find the .lib files. Next step is to run procmon from sysinternals while you compile, you will be able to see what directories its looking in and what files its looking for