# `__declspec(dllexport) extern std::string foo;` not found by linker

Tags: c++, extern, dllexport

I ran into the same problem as mentioned here:
[Protobuf - Refuses to link vs2013 or vs2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39280178/protobuf-refuses-to-link-vs2013-or-vs2015)

I figured out that these two lines in *generated_message_util.h* may cause that problem:

```
__declspec(dllexport) extern const ::std::string* empty_string_;
__declspec(dllexport) extern ProtobufOnceType empty_string_once_init_;
```

See: https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/src/google/protobuf/generated_message_util.h#L80

I am not that detailed familiar with the keyword `extern` but at the end the linker which tries to use that libarary can not find the two definitions of These variables, which are done in *generated_message_util.cc*.

```
const ::std::string* empty_string_;
GOOGLE_PROTOBUF_DECLARE_ONCE(empty_string_once_init_);

void InitEmptyString() {
  empty_string_ = new string;
  ...
}
```

See: https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/src/google/protobuf/generated_message_util.cc#L51 and following lines.

Does someone know a good workaround for this issue, with that information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that your compiler flags and defined preprocessor symbols are set correctly.

`__declspec(dllexport)` should be set for creation of the DLL, and your code needs to contain the definition. If you want to use the DLL, then you need `__declspec(dllimport)`.

See the `port.h`file (src/google/protobuf/stubs/port.h) for the definition of `LIBPROTOBUF_EXPORT`. It depends on `LIBPROTOBUF_EXPORTS`, so if you want to **create** the DLL, make sure that `LIBPROTOBUF_EXPORTS` **is** defined. If you want to **use** the DLL, make sure that `LIBPROTOBUF_EXPORTS` **is not** defined.

In order to identify the problem, you can insert the following code in your project:

```
#ifdef LIBPROTOBUF_EXPORTS
#error defining LIBPROTOBUF_EXPORTS only allowed on DLL creation!
#endif

#ifndef PROTOBUF_USE_DLLS
#error defining PROTOBUF_USE_DLLS is required for DLL usage!
#endif
```

It will lead to a compile error if your symbols are wrongly defined. Then you still need to fix your project settings until the conditions are satisfied. I can't help you with it, given the current information.

If the conditions don't trigger the error and the problem persists, there might be something else going on, worth looking into it more detailed.

Comment: `LIBPROTOBUF_EXPORTS` and 
`PROTOBUF_USE_DLLS` are defined in in the library project preprocessor settings. The application using this lib has non of them defined.

Comment: @MatthiasLochbrunner then your question title doesn't make much sense... `LIBPROTOBUF_EXPORT` shouldn't expand to `__declspec(dllexport)` unless `PROTOBUF_USE_DLLS` and `LIBPROTOBUF_EXPORTS` are defined. Please re-check.

Comment: @MatthiasLochbrunner I assume that you actually work with the code that you linked and not with a modified code, where `LIBPROTOBUF_EXPORT` was already expanded, as in your question code.

Comment: @ grek40 Yes I modified the code only here for better reading. PS. Now I use the bad hack with `LIBPROTOBUF_EXPORT inline const ::std::string& GetEmptyStringAlreadyInited() {
  return "";
}`  which seems to work. If you know a nicer solution. I am open to any approvments.

Comment: @MatthiasLochbrunner see my edit for a way to make the problem visible. Don't use a hack, just make sure that the symbols are really defined like you think they are.