# The system cannot find the file specified Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

I just started programming, but I keep on getting problems with headers and stuff.
So, whenever I try and run the code

```
 // ConsoleApplication4.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console      application.
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

I get this warning saying

> *Unable to start program 'C:\Users\Gebruiker\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ConsoleApplication4\Debug\ConsoleApplication4.exe'.
>   The system cannot find file specified.*

Additionally, the Build outputs:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: ConsoleApplication4, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>ConsoleApplication4.cpp
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\hash_map(17): error C2338: <hash_map> is deprecated and will be REMOVED. Please use <unordered_map>. You can define _SILENCE_STDEXT_HASH_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS to acknowledge that you have received this warning.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========_
```

As you might've noticed, I'm following Bjarne Stroustrup's book on this, and he doesn't specify how to deal with this at all.

Anyways, the *std_lib_facilities.h* header is in the same folder as *ConsoleApplication.cpp*, just as he tells me to do.

I don't actually think this has anything to do with this program in particular, since I face this problem with all the projects I make.

Oh yes, I have to say that I've checked multiple related questions to this, but the questions didn't match mine.

I also tried to `#include "../std_lib_facilities.h"` and `#include "../../std_lib_facilities.h"`, with no results.(Same with *stdafx.h*) I've tried "building" the program, but I don't actually know what that does, and if I should build the solution or the cpp, and when to debug....

The answer surely isn't in the book, since I've continued on to chapter 8, not doing the exercises because I cannot get the thing to work.

(Please also tell me if I messed something up in this question, i.e. that I need to talk less, give more details or something)

Comment: [comments archived](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/134857)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Try creating "new project" / C++ console application; with your code and without any include statements.* - [Peter K](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2014022/peter-k)

This fixed the problem for me, and I basically just copy-pasted the code and it worked.

I also had the hash_map error, because it is no longer supported in MSVS 2017. 
This especially happens since one often still finds the old header off of Bjarne Stroustrup's website. Here is the link to the [new header](http://stroustrup.com/Programming/PPP2code/std_lib_facilities.h) provided by [Baum Mit Augen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3002139/baum-mit-augen) (Stroustrup's updated version)

If you're not using the header provided by Bjarne Stroustrup but one you made yourself, one you found on the internet or also one provided by a book, follow [this tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30811441/6639082) from a previous answer by [WindyFields](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6639082/windyfields). (Thanks a lot for that) (Be sure to check their answer out if this doesn't fix it)

If you encountered this problem, you probably messed with the settings when making a new project (like me).

> This is a condensation of the comments provided by the community, none of these answers are mine.

Comment: [Archived the comments](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/134857) so that they are not lost.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to remove a deprecation error:
[How to fix "<hash_map> is deprecated and will be REMOVED. Please use <unordered_map>"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30811441/6639082)

If it still does not run, just go to the project directory and remove all Debug\Release folders Visual Studio creates after you run with Debug\Release configuration. Usually works for me.